# jRuby's Float to represent in JTable's cell

Tags: floating-point, jtable, jruby

I need to represent floats in jTable formatted.
When I do `tbl.model.add_row [obj, 1.3524632478].to_java`, obj is represented as it's to_s method's return value, but float do not. Overriding float's to_s method does nothing.
I want floats to be formatted like this
`class Float
    def to_s
        sprintf("%.2f", self)
    end
end`
in all my tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby classes are converted to java classes when rows being vectorized. I added to_s method to java's Float class and its OK

Answer (score 0):

I would surmise that it's due to the default TableCellRenderer used calling `java.lang.Float.toString(some_float)` rather than `some_float.to_s`. So in addition to what you've already done with Float's to_s, add these:

```
class MyCellRenderer < Java::JavaxSwingTable::DefaultTableCellRenderer::UIResource
    def setValue(value)
        setText(value.nil? ? "" : value.to_s)
    end
end
my_cell_renderer = MyCellRenderer.new

# This to set it globally
my_table.setDefaultRenderer(java.lang.Object, my_cell_renderer)

# Or this to set it for specific columns only
my_table.column_model.getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(my_cell_renderer)
```